# Variable does not exist - Batch Apex Query and Expression cannot be a statement

Tags: apex, batch

```
String query = 

'SELECT id,Email,name,MailingCountry,active__C,ECP_Flag__c,Chrun_Indicator__c,Sales_Program_Type__c FROM contact '+' where AccountId!= null and account.Active__c='yes' and (Account.Type like 'Customer +'%'') and Active__c='Yes'and Email!= null and (NOT Email  like ' '%' + sap.com')';

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

Comment: Please do not delete posts where members of the community have engaged and provided answers. This is a public knowledge base and we expect future readers to find value in questions and answers here.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing dynamic in this query.

```
SELECT id,Email,name,MailingCountry,active__C,ECP_Flag__c,Chrun_Indicator__c,Sales_Program_Type__c
FROM contact
WHERE AccountId!= null and account.Active__c='yes' and (Account.Type like 'Customer%') and Active__c='Yes'and Email!= null and (NOT Email  like '%Equinix.com')
```

However, you have a number of locations where you have failed to correctly concatenate strings or escape embedded quotes. Avoid this issue by writing your query inline instead of as a string:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([QUERY HERE]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are converting your SOQL in a string, you need to escape `'` using `\`.

Something like this:

```
String query = SELECT id,Email,name,MailingCountry,active__C,ECP_Flag__c,Chrun_Indicator__c,Sales_Program_Type__c FROM contact where AccountId != null and Account.Active__c= \'yes\' and (Account.Type like \'Customer%\') and Active__c = \'Yes\' and Email != null and (NOT Email  like \'%sap.com\')';

System.debug(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
```

Also before deploying your queries to batch directly you can just use `anonymous apex` to just check of your string SOQL is compiled successfully and works correctly.